# PhoneGap Implementing BarCode Scanner on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am very new to PhoneGap and am trying to implement the barcodescanner app to execute on a button click.  I have added the following to the config.xml:

```
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.2.0" />
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />      
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/jQuery.mmenu-master/demo/css/demo.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/jQuery.mmenu-master/dist/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.mmenu-master/dist/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('click','#employeeScan',function(e) {    
            $("#results").html("I am now scanning");
            window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result){
                $("#results").html("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" + 
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + 
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            }, function(error){
                $("#results").html("Scanning failed: " + error);
            });
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div class="header">

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <button id="employeeScan">Scan Badge</button>
            <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click the button, I see the initial "I am now scanning" text but that is it.  I do not know if the plugin is configured correctly.

Comment: are you using phonegap build service or are you doing local development?

Comment: Local deployment for now

Comment: So you have to install the plugin using the cli, putting that line on the config.xml only works on phonegap build

Comment: I just tried the code using the phonegap build and it shows the plugin as being associated to the project, but nothing happens when I click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result){
```

USE:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result(){
```